# Unity3D Ground Check Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unity3d-editor

So I have a ground object called **Player** which has a Collider and animator attached to it. I am trying to sucessfully check if the player "is grounded" by reading the collision of the player with a plane called (and tagged) **Ground**.

My Player has a RigidBody and my Collider attached to said player has a Mesh Collider that is Convex attached to it. I am using the below script that is attached to my Player to see if I am grounded or touching the Ground plane. It does not return the player as grounded when it is standing on top of the plane.

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Physics.BoxCast(transform.position, boxSize, -player.up, out hit, Quaternion.Euler(collider.eulerAngles), distance, mask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
        {
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Ground")
            {
                isGrounded = true;
                groundNormal = hit.normal;
            }
            else
            {
                isGrounded = false;
                groundNormal = Vector3.up;                          // if were in the air or not touching something then gravity is always set down.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            groundNormal = Vector3.up;
        }
    }
```

I have tried editing the Player gameobject components to see if there is an issue with my box size or distance, but nothing seems to work. I have attached a screenshot below with my Player inspector window. The "Is Grounded" box should be checked while my player is touching the Ground plane, but it is not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lufk.png)

Comment: do some debugging, what is it hitting, what tag is it, perhaps you need to check for jsut ground.. and not anything else, such as maybe your mask is wrong

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with debugging through unity, I did try the Physics Debugger and from what I can tell, the Mesh Collider is making contact with the player rigid body, which makes sense since it isn't falling through the floor. The tag is correct as well. I am wondering if Physics.BoxCast does not work with Mesh Colliders.

Comment: Put in debug statements they show in the console

Comment: Since actual collisions are working, try using Debug.DrawLine [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) to check if your raycast is where you think it should be. Alternatively, you could use another collider with "isTrigger" enabled and use OnTriggerEnter/Exit to change the grounded state instead of doing a boxcast every Frame.